# Estimate future growth using sample of historical data

Tags: python, r, approximation

I have historical records of the growth (in terms of size) of our database for past couple of years. I am trying to figure out the best way/graph that can show me the future growth of database based on the historical records, of course this won't help if we add a new table and that would grow too, but I am just looking for a way to estimate it. I am open to ideas in Python or R

Here is the size of the database in TB over years:

3.895 - 2012
6.863 - 2013
8.997 - 2014
10.626 - 2015

Comment: You need some idea of what kind of growth you are getting each year.  Is it linear?  Polynomial?  Exponential?  Logistic?  

Also, how familar are you with R?

Comment: Univariate time series models may be used if predictor variables don't exist. Also the storage variable to predict would need to be transformed (eg log(s1) - log(s0)) so that it is more bell-shaped. The forecast package may be useful.

Comment: I have added the db size info, if that helps.

Comment: @user1362215: Looks to me that the growth is polynomial. I am familiar enough that I can find my way through writing a script. I know there are many packages in R that would have algorithms already implemented and it might just be the case that I need to feed it this data, the point is which algorithm/package would help me

Comment: I don't believe any algorithm is helpful with such a few records. I may look for moving average.

Comment: With 4 records, I would probably just look at a linear model, since 4 time points is too small to really handle any amount of complexity unless it is extremely obvious.  e.g., you had 1, 4.1, 9.2, and 16.3 each year

Comment: Would it be more helpful if I break it down to per month basis? And what were those values: 1, 4.1, 9.2?

Comment: Per month would probably help.  I assume the values given are the sizes scaled by the initial size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(x= 2012:2015,
            y = c(3.895, 6.863, 8.997, 10.626))
```

You can visualize the fit (and its projection):  here I'm comparing an additive and a polynomial model.  I'm not sure I believe the confidence intervals on the additive model, though:

```
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+ geom_point() +
    expand_limits(x=2018)+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~poly(x,2),
                fullrange=TRUE,fill="blue")+
    geom_smooth(method="gam",formula=y~s(x,k=3),colour="red",
                fullrange=TRUE,fill="red")
```

[image]

I'm a little shocked the quadratic relationship is so close.

```
summary(m1 <- lm(y~poly(x,2),data=d))
## Residual standard error: 0.07357 on 1 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.9998, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9994 
## F-statistic:  2344 on 2 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.0146
```

Predict:

```
predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(x=2016:2018),interval="confidence")
##        fit      lwr      upr
## 1 11.50325 8.901008 14.10549
## 2 11.72745 6.361774 17.09313
## 3 11.28215 2.192911 20.37139
```

Did you make up these numbers, or are they real data?

The `forecast()` package would be better for more sophisticated methods.

Comment: Your answer could use your plot to show off the coolness of ggplot: https://i.imgur.com/1J9ZcXF.png

And I'd like to see how you would use `predict()` to see e.g. data for 2016, and how that can be incorporated into the plot, if possible.

Comment: "Did you make up these numbers, or are they real data?": nope, that's real data

Comment: This is really nice. R shines here.

Answer (score 5):

Gluing a few pieces of numpy and scipy together you can make a decent approximation using the first and second derivatives of the continuous approximation of your usage data.

There are likely better ways to do this but this works for me.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

x = np.array([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])
y = np.array([3.895, 6.863, 8.997, 10.626])

# interpolate to approximate a continuous version of hard drive usage over time
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')

# approximate the first and second derivatives near the last point (2015)
dx = 0.01
x0 = x[-1] - 2*dx
first = scipy.misc.derivative(f, x0, dx=dx, n=1)
second = scipy.misc.derivative(f, x0, dx=dx, n=2)

# taylor series approximation near x[-1]
forecast = lambda x_new: np.poly1d([second/2, first, f(x[-1])])(x_new - x[-1])
forecast(2016)  # 11.9

xs = np.arange(2012, 2020)
ys = forecast(xs)

# needed to prevent matplotlib from putting the x-axis in scientific notation
x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)  
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)

plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also do this with ``scipy.optimize.curve_fit`` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Answer (score 3):

On second thought, what you really want to use is a [Gaussian Process](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html).

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.gaussian_process
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

np.random.seed(1)

X = np.atleast_2d([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]).T
y = np.array([3.895, 6.863, 8.997, 10.626])

x_new = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(2012, 2018, 1000)).T

gp = sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess()
gp.fit(X, y)
y_pred, MSE = gp.predict(x_new, eval_MSE=True)
sigma = np.sqrt(MSE)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(prediction=y_pred, se=sigma), index=x_new)
df.plot(yerr='se')
```

While the fundamentals are strong, Python needs better visualization libraries. Even getting the x-axis to display integers (instead of using scientific notation) is unnecessarily difficult.

[image]

Comment: How do we extract the forecast range?